# return function to reactDOM does nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Why this doesn't work? I was following a youtube tutorial.

```
function Hello(props) {
  return <div>Hello</div>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
   Hello,
   document.getElementById('entry')
);
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmqJGp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the JS console of that page you will see the following:

[image]

Following that link, the [error page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=39&args[]=%20Instead%20of%20passing%20a%20class%20like%20Foo%2C%20pass%20React.createElement(Foo)%20or%20%3CFoo%20%2F%3E) states

> ReactDOM.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a class like Foo, pass React.createElement(Foo) or `<Foo />`

so instead of

```
ReactDOM.render(
   Hello,
   document.getElementById('entry')
);
```

you should do

```
ReactDOM.render(
   <Hello />,
   document.getElementById('entry')
);
```